# How to run JavaScript in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I want to use Google maps JavaScript library isLocationOnEgde function who can I use this function in c#.
I want to use islocationonedge and containslocation function from Google maps JavaScript library for geometry.

Comment: Short answer is you can't, but they will just be based on a formula you can implement in C#.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, do you know that formulas #Jamiec

Comment: Nope, but you may well find something on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Spherical_polygons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can port Google's Java implementation to C# found here

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L139

The page contains implementations for isLocationOnEdge and containsLocation as well as many other of the methods in the Google maps js library.

Answer (score 0):

Long answer is, you can. But you'll need to rope in a third-party tool unless you want to build your own JavaScript engine bridge.

Here's an example of someone who wrote a bridge between the Chakra JS Engine (what Edge uses) and C#:
https://www.sitepoint.com/using-javascript-frameworks-inside-c-with-chakrabridge/